# Help me be familar with the rules in Gentzen's proof system.

Tags: logic

I'm learning Getzen's sequent proof system. However, I have only one book on hand, and I don't really like the explanation by the book. Now I'm stuck in understanding the soundness of the rule. Hope you can help me.

For example,

$\neg$-L Rule:$\dfrac{\Gamma,\Delta\vdash A,\Lambda}{\Gamma,\neg A,\Delta\vdash\Lambda}$

Does the bar mean that $\Gamma,\Delta\vdash A,\Lambda$ if and only if $\Gamma,\neg A,\Delta\vdash\Lambda$? And how do we prove this(or intutively understand this)? Suppose $\Gamma,\Delta\vdash A,\Lambda$, then  every model satisfies all sentences in $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ also satisfies at least one sentence in $A$ and $\Lambda$. And then for every model satisfies $\Gamma$ and $\neg A$ and $\Delta$, why does it satisfy at least one sentence in $\Lambda$? (This direction may not be too difficult, but the converse seems complicated.) Is there a fast way in mind to think this, and to get familar with Getzen's rule?

Comment: Not "if and only if". You only get from above the bar to below the bar. Also, arguing with models is about semantic implication ($\vDash$), not syntactic implication ($\vdash$), but probably the best way to understand why we gladly accept this syntactic rule

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there an exception that can be downward and upward? Another question, if $\vee$-L Rule require two brances simutaneously true to infer the lower sentence?

Comment: No. Whenever we'd want downward and upward (i.e., equivalence), we'd express that as two rules of inference with top and bottom swapped (and be it only to avoid confusion). -- The natural language interpretation of $$\begin{align}A&\vdash B\\C&\vdash D\\\hline E&\vdash F\end{align}$$ is "If $A$ entails $B$ and $C$ entails $D$, then we can infer that $E$ entails $F$".

Comment: @Eric : conventionnally, inference rules are always directed downwards. Of course it can happen that the "reverse" of an inference rule can be proved as well, but those cases are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you all. By the way, which mathematical books has an introduction on sequent proof system? I found that Enderton, Ebbinghaus and Chiswell&Hodges's text do not include this.

Comment: Since you were asking about intuitive understanding: If from some knowledge we can infer that one of two possibilities $p_1, p_2$ must hold, then if we learn later that $p_1$ is in fact false, we can infer that $p_2$ must be true (and vice versa). This is essentially what the rule says.